# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u03c7' in position 66: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, unicode, flask

I sometimes get this error on my web server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
    return _active[_get_ident()]
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1690, in wsgi_app
    return response(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 1082, in __call__
    app_iter, status, headers = self.get_wsgi_response(environ)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 1072, in get_wsgi_response
    return app_iter, self.status, headers.to_list()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 1141, in to_list
    for k, v in self]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u03c7' in position 66: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The problem is that I have no idea where this happens in my code, so I don't know where I should put the .encode('utf-8', 'ignore').

Comment: You don't know your code but you are asking others for help? That's pretty lazy, concerning the fact that the "where" is pretty well answered by the backtrace.

Comment: u'\u03c7' is char χ, have idea where it is?

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear, the latin char comes from user input, as their's no such thing in my code

Comment: i just don't know where, as everything referenced in the stacktrace is either internal to python or flask

Comment: also i'm not able to reproduce locally, which would be much easier

Comment: You're setting a header with a non-ISO-8859-1 character in its value, which is invalid. In general it is a bad idea to be writing user-supplied content into a header.

Comment: yes, that seems to be it, thank you bobince

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be trying to set a header that has a character not in the ISO-8859-1 character set.  Currently, HTTP headers must only contain characters from that codec.  More recent versions of Werkzeug require the Latin-1 codec instead to more closely follow the WSGI spec.

[See this Flask issue for a message about this from the maintainer.](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/772#issuecomment-19602873)  It mentions that the correct way to use characters outside the range is described in [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987), which may be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Put a:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

in:
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in **call**

Restart the app and check vars values in your terminal.
Press "n" for "next".
Use "print var_name" to see a value for a variable.
Read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: i'm not able to reproduce locally

Comment: Test it on server. Use vim to change the file.

Comment: actually i'm not able to reproduce even on server, i don't what user behavior causes this

Comment: ideally i would like to know where in my code the error is raised, so that i can add a filter